# shell script inserting "$" into a formatted column and adding new column

Tags: shell, ubuntu

Hi guys pardon for my bad English. I manage to display out my data nicely and neatly using column program in the code. But how do i add a "$" in the price column. Secondly how do i add a new column total sum to it and display it with "$". (Price * Sold)

```
(echo "Title:Author:Price:Quantity:Sold" && cat BookDB.txt) | column -s: -t
```

Output:

```
Title                        Author               Price   Quantity  Sold
The Godfather                Mario Puzo           21.50   50        20
The Hobbit                   J.R.R Tolkien        40.50   50        10
Romeo and Juliet             William Shakespeare  102.80  200       100
The Chronicles of Narnia     C.S.Lewis            35.90   80        15
Lord of the Flies            William Golding      29.80   125       25
Memories of a Geisha         Arthur Golden        35.99   120       50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could do it with awk (line break added before `&&` for readability

```
(echo "Title:Author:Price:Quantity:Sold:Calculated" 
&& awk -F: '{printf ("%s:%s:$%d:%d:%d:%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$3*$5)}' BookDB.txt) | column -s: -t
```

Comment: hi is giving me error "./Functions.sh: line 119: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied"

Comment: try it without the <() part (i've changed the answer)

Comment: The code works but my $3 and last column is double but is not showing the decimal point and how do i insert a "$" into it?

Comment: Just add the $ to the first part of printf